# Dropping tables in sqlite3 in ruby

Tags: ruby, sqlite

I am trying to drop a table from a database. However I keep getting an error. The code and the error message are below. Appreciate your help. The table  csv_07-15-2014_10-00 is present in the DB.

```
require 'win32ole'
require 'sqlite3'
DB_NAME = 'excel.db'

db = SQLite3::Database.new(DB_NAME)

sqlQuery =  "SELECT * FROM sqlite_master  WHERE type = 'table'"
puts db.execute(sqlQuery )

sqlQuery =  "DROP TABLE csv_07-15-2014_10-00"

puts sqlQuery
puts db.execute(sqlQuery)
```

Error message is below:

```
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.9-x86-mingw32/lib/sqlite3/databa
se.rb:91:in `initialize': near "-": syntax error (SQLite3::SQLException)
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.9-x86-mingw32/lib/s
qlite3/database.rb:91:in `new'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.9-x86-mingw32/lib/s
qlite3/database.rb:91:in `prepare'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.9-x86-mingw32/lib/s
qlite3/database.rb:134:in `execute'
        from sqldroptable.rb:19:in `<main>'
```

PUT Statement output is below:

```
table
csv_07-15-2014_10-00
csv_07-15-2014_10-00
2
CREATE TABLE [csv_07-15-2014_10-00] 
( mineId,prod_year,prod_qtr,subunit_cd,subunit,qtr_hrs,coal_prod,avg_emp_cnt )

table
csv_07-14-2014_22-30
csv_07-14-2014_22-30
8
CREATE TABLE [csv_07-14-2014_22-30] 
( mineId,prod_year,prod_qtr,subunit_cd,subunit,qtr_hrs,coal_prod,avg_emp_cnt )

table
csv_07-14-2014_22-29
csv_07-14-2014_22-29
9
CREATE TABLE [csv_07-14-2014_22-29]         
( mineId,prod_year,prod_qtr,subunit_cd,subunit,qtr_hrs,coal_prod,avg_emp_cnt )

DROP TABLE csv_07-15-2014_10-00 FROM sqlite_maste
```

r

Comment: The CREATE TABLE statements seem to need to qualify the table names by surrounding them with [].  Try the same with the DROP statement?

Answer (score 0):

You have SQL exception i think problem in escaping query try this:

```
sqlQuery =  "DROP TABLE \"csv_07-15-2014_10-00\""
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL, `-` is the subtraction operator, which does not make sense in a DROP TABLE statement.

If you have special characters in an identifier, you must quote it:

```
sqlQuery = "DROP TABLE [csv_07-15-2014_10-00]"
```

or

```
sqlQuery = "DROP TABLE \"csv_07-15-2014_10-00\""
```

or

```
sqlQuery = "DROP TABLE `csv_07-15-2014_10-00`"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Thanks to SO my learning curve has been exponential :)